# Avoiding Website content select and copy

Tags: drupal-6

I am using Drupal 6. In drupal how to avoid the user to copying the web page contents.How to disable it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a java script code to disable the content copy.
I pasted that code into body of the page and set input format into php code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var donotconsidortag = ["input", "textarea", "select"]
    donotconsidortag = donotconsidortag.join("|")
    function unableToSelect(e) {
        if (donotconsidortag.indexOf(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase()) == -1)
            return false
    }
    function ableToSelect() {
        return true
    }
    if (typeof document.onselectstart != "undefined")
        document.onselectstart = new Function("return false")
    else {
        document.onmousedown = unableToSelect
        document.onmouseup = ableToSelect
    }
</script>
```

For the particular content type use " content template " module and past the above code in to content template's textarea.In this we can disable the content select option for whole content type(For ex:Page or Story)

Comment: Okay, but you realize that this can be circumvented by simply turning JavaScript off in your browser?

Answer (score 6):

Ultimately ... **you can't**.

Even if you try some fancy JavaScript or some fancy image over, etc., a user can just press `Ctrl+A` (select all) and then `Ctrl+C` (copy). There is a plethora of ways to get information from a web-site such as development environment (FireBug), alternative agents (wget/curl), or even using a browser not "protected" with the scheme.

Bottom line ... the only way to prevent someone from "keeping" that data is by *not giving them access to begin with*. Alternatively, make the user(s) sign an NDA/agreement and hire lawyers :-)

Happy doing productive things.

---

If all that is desired is prevent a "select" with a mouse, then an img-over may work. Alternatively, send back non-text (e.g. images containing the text) content and/or embed the content into Flash or another relatively controlled plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

```
<SCRIPT language=JavaScript>
    var message = "function disabled"; 
    function rtclickcheck(keyp){ if (navigator.appName == "Netscape" && keyp.which == 3){   alert(message); return false; } 
    if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE") != -1 && event.button == 2) {  alert(message);     return false; } } 
    document.onmousedown = rtclickcheck;
</SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to prevent a determined user from accessing the content of your web page.  Tools like firebug, and a plethora of screen capture software easily circumvent any such attempts.

To make it difficult for unsophisticated or lazy users, you could overlay a transparent 1x1 image over the top of the entire page, or content you are trying to protect.

```
<img src="transparent.png" style = "width:100%; height:100%;position:absolute;" />
```